# Extending a gradle subproject's clean and build behavior

Tags: java, gradle

I use a program called TexturePacker to pack individual image assets into a single texture atlas for use in-game.  My usual workflow is to add/change the assets, then manually re-pack the images using the GUI or command line, with the output being sent to the projects resource folder where it remains under source control.  This works, but it's tedious.  At any rate, it feels more "right" to have the individual assets be within the project's root folder under source control, and have the "pack to textureAtlas" step be an automated part of of the build.  Analogous to how we keep source code under VC but not the build-related files.

So my question becomes, how can I do this with gradle?

As far as I can tell the steps would be:

.gitignore the output folder (easy)

Hook into the subproject's Clean task, and delete the output folder (in main/resources)

Hook into subproject's build task (or wherever's most appropriate), and run the JAR from gradle.

I found an article about running JARs from gradle and it seems straightforward, but the rest baffles me.  I realize this is probably a really basic question, I just have some sort of mental block with gradle, I just can't wrap my head around it for some reason.  Anyway, my question is how to best approach this problem; hopefully that'll help me get a handle on gradle in general.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about Gradle is the "steps" you are describing are mostly handled for you if you define your task properly. So to directly answer your questsions.

1. Just put your build outputs in the normal 'build' folder with the rest of your Gradle output (classes, jars, etc). No need to add another folder to .gitignore.
2. If you define your input/outputs correctly (shown below) Gradle will take care of this for you.
3. Just add your new task as a dependency to whatever other task is appropriate. In many cases, simply the 'assemble' task.

If you are using an executable jar to create your texture you'll probably want to use the `JavaExec` task.

```
task buildTextures(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.dir 'textures/dir'
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/textures"

    jvmArgs '-jar', 'somejar.jar'
    args // arguments to executable jar main class
}

assemble.dependsOn buildTextures
```

By specifying the inputs/outputs Gradle will take care of deleting the output directories when doing a `clean`. Additionally, you get incremental build support, meaning that this task will run again if the input directory contents change.

Comment: This is way cleaner than I expected, and I love the incremental build support.  Thanks!